# How to package module.modulemap into CocoaTouch Swift Framework?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am trying to create a CocoaTouch Swift Framework which I can then distribute to 3rd parties for them to use, and I can build it and use it ok on my machine.

The issues arise when I give it to other people.
My framework uses C code, which I make available for use with Swift within my framework via a `module.modulemap` file as such:

[image: Project Setup]
[image: Module Map]

And I am able to use such module in a Swift file, within the framework, ok, as such:

[image]

However, when I build the framework and give it to other people to use, their compiler complains that the Minzip module is missing with the message `Missing required module 'Minizip'`.

Having investigated, it seems like I'd have to make the users of my framework modify their **Swift Compiler - Search Paths -> Import Paths** the same way I have to do it to have my compiler find the `module.modulemap`.

Is there a way that I can build the framework so that I don't have to do this?